# Excel Security Warning Enable Content

Tags: vba, excel

The first time I open a new version of my excel aplication, I get a securutiy warning.  I click Enable Content but the Workbook Events that need to initialise the application don't fire.

After I close the workbook and open it again it will be fine - the Security Warning does not appear and all of the events fire as designed.

I'm not sure if this behaviour will be the same for all users and I would prefer not to ask them to just close it and re-open if it happens.
I think I can ask the users to create a trusted folder and I will investigate that option as a solution, but is there any way to avoid the problem all together?

I can't use a subsequent event that in any way references the sheet I want to configure (for example right-click or sheet activate, even in the ThisWorkbook Module).  This is because I have OLEobjects on the sheet, which are stored in a Global Collection and the Collection will be un-loaded if I, in any way, reference the source sheet.

Is there any other way to work arround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this behaviour will be the same for all users

It is. There is no fix for it yet and I doubt there will be. You will have to close and re-open the file.

> Is there any way to avoid the problem all together

No... Not that I am aware of. The only way is what you already know. Ask the users to create a trusted folder. More on [Trusted Documents](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/trusted-documents-HA010354384.aspx)

Comment: OK, no problem. Thanks for the very clear answer and helpfull link  @SiddharthRout